# How to show ads to users without Google Play Services installed

Tags: android, google-play-services, ads

My app uses Google Play Services to show ads (Google Mobile Ads). But I have a problem - when Google Play Services are installed, the ads are correctly shown. But if I delete Google Play Services, these ads are gone.
Is it possible to show Google Mobile Ads when Google play services are not installed? Otherwise, can I "require" that Google Play Services are available when launching my app?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative may be you can use google admob sdk instead from the play services. proceed as follows:

1. just download the Google ad mob sdk from the link

http://www.mediafire.com/download/f9td9rxm2mwabuc/admob_ads_sdk_11.zip

2. unzip it somewhere or  in the desktop
3. search for. jar file inside libs folder
4. Now copy this googleadmobssdk.jar file  into the libs folder of your project
5. Right click on the project and look for the properties .click it and look for java build path.
6. click add jar,  then locate the libs folder u had copied just before.
   7.Done but
   You need to implement slightly bit different attributes and methods than in the normal google play services use. Google ,to get its sample code..

Comment: But...
"The Google Mobile Ads SDK for Android is now a part of the Google Play services platform. It is no longer available as a standalone SDK."

"On August 1, 2014, the Play Store will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the standalone Google AdMob SDK. The standalone SDK does not use the Advertising ID, and will therefore be non-compliant with the Google Play Ad Policy on this date."